# How did half of Darth Maul survive?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

From what I have read on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Maul), Darth Maul survived by using the Force, drawing from his hate to hang to a air vent, but then what? He crawled to a spaceship with his entrails sliding out?

Comment: From what you’ve read “on here”? I don’t see anything: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=darth+maul+survive Where did you read this?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Maul) has this: "Through his intense rage, Maul was able to survive and escape to the junk fields Lotho Minor, where he spent the next twelve years of his life with little to no memory of his former self."

Comment: Just when I thought Star Wars couldn't jump the shark any further...

Comment: Meat Trademark is correct, Maul's survival is a very sad plot device to get a familiar villain onto the TV show.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - No. THAT would be when we have a [Jedi](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQ1XKiZc3She85vtieHKd7QdlFzhLrRmpTF3r4wpt1pg_HfMf2YA) [shark](http://drawception.com/pub/panels/2012/4-2/82BCTRbBHP-8.png). Or, a Jedi astromech droid. Oh... [never mind](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid). Meesa gonna go cry in the corner.

Comment: @DVK , When did Jabberjaw become a Jedi?

Comment: Let Joss Whedon kill some Star Wars chacters so they'll **stay** dead.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - Salvatore DID that. Alas, poor Chewie. AND poor Anakin Solo.

Comment: because the dark side of the force is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Maul#Defeat) has the answer, with references:

> However, Maul managed to survive his defeat at the hands of Kenobi. Through his hate and will to live, as well as his hatred against Kenobi, **he reached out with the Force and grabbed an air vent.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXpJt.jpg) He went down the reactor shaft and landed in water. The Sith Lord was then dumped into a container, which was taken to Lotho Minor**. As he lay submerged, he fell into unconsciousness, cursing Kenobi.

THe references are: *Star Wars: The Wrath of Darth Maul* and *Star Wars: The Clone Wars: The Sith Hunters*

---

**UPDATE**:

Here's the proof from the first book, regarding air vent:

> As his remains tumbled down the generator shaft, he kept his eyes open and fought to remain conscious. But then his head struck the shaft’s wall, and everything went dark.
>   *No!*
>   His mind screamed. Despite everything he had learned about death and duty from his Master, Maul knew he was not yet ready to die. Not after so many years of training, and with so much more to accomplish. Not so long as he still had so much hatred within him.
>   ...
>   *Can’t die!*
>   He fell past an oval shadow, and then a similar shadow raced by, along with a whooshing sound.
>   **Maul hoped that there was at least one more vent below, that it would be large enough to accommodate his diminished body.** He extended his arms, and his left hand’s fingertips suddenly burned with friction as they brushed against the cylindrical wall.
>   *Must live!*
>   **Hoping, wishing, praying for one more air vent...**
>   *Must kill Obi-Wan!*
>   ...he reached out with the Force.

---

And, from [Sith Hunters comic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars:_The_Sith_Hunters), here's how he got to Lotho Minor (Pages 25/26):

> *IMAGE: 2 halves of Maul lying in some sort of a sludge pool*
>   **Obi-Wan:** "The Sith crave life above all else, Padawan... They wish to control it, dominated it, and thus cling to it with every fiber of their being
>
> *IMAGE: Maul looks really angry*
>   "I believe Maul's **rage** was so powerful, and his **knowledge** of Dark Side so great, he simply **refused** to die.
>
> *IMAGE: Maul's body being sucked down the drain with the sludge*
>   "... But it is not impossible that 'other forces' contributed to Maul's survival

... And on Page 26/27, they show him falling into some sort of a vat, and a ship picking up those vats and dropping them off on Lotho Minor:

[image] [image]

Comment: I'm still confused. If he fell unconscious, wouldn't he have stopped using the Force to maintain his life and then just died? Or was his hatred so pervasive that it continued to be effective, even in unconsciousness?

Comment: +1 for your damn answer and -1000000000 for Lucas approving this damn answer. :(

Comment: @MeatTrademark - Lucas doesn't usually "approve" of individual C-canon things. Lucasfilm team mostly does).

Comment: The Force works in mysterious ways Matt

Comment: "Lucas doesn't usually "approve" of individual C-canon things. Lucasfilm team mostly does)" I remember reading long ago, in the early days of the EU books (probably an issue of SW Insider), that Lucas was given plot details and that so long as they didn't directly contradict his master plan, they were approved since they weren't fully cannon anyways.

Comment: @phantom42 - thus "usually" vs "never" :)

Comment: For the record, Maw (Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II) survived being cut in half first. Although, chronologically speaking, that happened AFTER Episode VI.

Comment: @DVK - Lucas apparently approved of this enough to include Darth Maul's survival in season 4 of the Clone Wars series, which he was very involved in ([this interview](http://herocomplex.latimes.com/tv/star-wars-the-clone-wars-head-writer-talks-about-george-lucas-religion-and-the-shows-lifespan/) talks about him 'steering the stories' and writing outlines for individual episodes), enough so that it was [decided](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page) to include it the new Disney canon, as one of the "immovable objects of Star Wars history".

Comment: I would point out that the primary cause of death when sliced in half like that would be massive blood loss. Given that a lightsaber would cauterize everything and add in an unconscious ability to use the force to hold himself together, and it's not unreasonable that he could survive until he starved to death. The moral would be, "Don't assume a Sith is dead until you've vaporized their brain." And maybe not even then for certain values of "dead".

Comment: That's no fair. The bad guy gets sliced in two and lives; the good guy gets poked and dies. [Who Needs Their Whole Body?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhoNeedsTheirWholeBody), [No One Could Survive That](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoOneCouldSurviveThat?from=Main.NoOneCouldHaveSurvivedThat), [Not Quite Dead](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NotQuiteDead). Plus, Dragon Ball Z did it first (right?)

Comment: "his left hand’s fingertips suddenly burned with friction" - one notices this while half his body is missing... sure. I assume this is meant to be a Naked Gun sequel?

Answer (score 4):

### Anger

Maul was so furious at being defeated by Obi-Wan that he was able to use his anger and thirst for revenge to keep himself alive.

> **Q**: How does Maul survive being cut in half?
>
> **A**: The power of anger! Maul draws on his master’s dark side lessons to
> harness his rage and stay alive after Obi-Wan maims him in a duel in
> Naboo. Rumor has it that his top half fell down a reactor shaft into a
> trash container, which was then shipped to Lotho Minor.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*</sub>

This came at a price, though: Maul lived in constant agony and was driven half-mad, with no memory of the Sith he had once been. Only through Mother Talzin’s dark side magicks was his memory restored.

Employing strong negative emotions such as rage has always been a sure-fire route to great dark side power:

> He falls and Luke is preparing to leap down after him when he hears
> the Emperor behind him.
>
> “Good. Use your aggressive feelings, boy. Let the hate flow through
> you.”
>
> Again, the Emperor is telling the truth and Luke knows it. He has won,
> but only by using the dark side of the Force. The hate is flowing
> through him and he is winning this battle against his father because
> of it.
>
> <sub>*Beware the Power of the Dark Side!*</sub>

In fact, it seems possible that something similar may also have aided in Darth Vader’s survival on Mustafar. Certainly he had plenty of hatred and anger going on there.

The strength of Maul’s hatred is such that he’s *still* trying to kill Obi-Wan as of the *Star Wars: Rebels* era, some three decades later.

In addition, different Force users can have different talents, somewhat independent of their raw power in the Force. Quinlan Vos could gain impressions of an object’s past by touching it, whereas Mother Talzin could create objects (such as a sword for combat) out of dark side energy. Presumably Maul has a particular aptitude for using the dark side to keep himself alive.

It’s also probably worth noting (though this has not been mentioned anywhere) that, as a [Zabrak](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zabrak), Maul may have had a somewhat different organ layout than the standard human, which might  have aided him in surviving. Further, the lightsaber may have provided some degree of cauterization, which would also be helpful.

Comment: The last paragraph here is the most helpful. Good thinking!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is that the movie doesn't show any evidence of him surviving as far as in the films..

In other media he survived after his defeat... for instance in the cartoons...

[from the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth_Maul)

> In the fourth season, Darth Maul himself returns. Having survived his
>   bisection, Maul was striving to survive by any means and ended up on
>   the junk planet Lotho Minor in the Outer Rim and turned into a cyborg
>   with an arachnid-like lower half and managed to survive with the help
>   of Anacondan Morley. Over the decade, Maul's mind sank into a
>   melancholy insanity before he was found by Savage Opress. Savage's
>   presence causes Maul to remember his downfall and resolves to have his
>   revenge. Brought back to Dathomir in the aftermath of the
>   Nightsisters' slaughter by Count Dooku's Separatists droids, Maul
>   undergoes a purging of his madness and is given a new pair of robotic
>   legs crafted by Talzin's magic. With his mind restored, Maul learns
>   that the Clone Wars have started without him.[4] With Savage's help,
>   he proceeds to extract revenge on Obi-Wan Kenobi by luring him into a
>   trap by attacking a small village on outer rim planet Raydonia,
>   knowing that the Jedi will come to assist. However, Asajj Ventress's
>   unexpected appearance to collect a high bounty placed on Savage
>   thwarts Maul's plan. Kenobi and Ventress duel Maul and Savage in the
>   cargo bay of Savage's stolen ship but soon realize that they are
>   outmatched and are forced to flee via the cockpit escape vessel. Maul
>   decides not to pursue the jettisoned pod but to wait for another
>   opportunity, realizing that the Jedi already know of his continued
>   existence through the Force.[5]

As stated by a previous answer he survived [through his rage](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Maul)

> Through his intense rage, Maul was able to survive and escape to the
>   junk fields Lotho Minor, where he spent the next twelve years of his
>   life with little to no memory of his former self.

Comment: I remember a comic book (but not which one) where a cyborg Maul fought Vader to see who was the more worthy Sith. Maul claimed to be the better Sith because he was never  Jedi and therefore had never been infected with compassion - his hatred was more "pure." Vader won by stabbing both himself and Maul through the chest. His hatred was greater because he hated himself.

Comment: @pleurocoelus that was an issue of Star Wars Tales. The version of Maul that fought Vader wasn't a cyborg but instead either a clone or a fully resurrected Maul (they never said).

Comment: Ah, thanks, @Omegacron. It had been a while.