# Did Emperor Palpatine Know Darth Maul Survived?

Tags: star-wars, sith, darth-sidious

Canonical sources say that Darth Maul actually survived after being defeated by Obi-Wan despite being cut in half.

[How did half of Darth Maul survive?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48305/how-did-half-of-darth-maul-survive)

Since Darth Maul survived, and Palpatine took in Anakin as an apprentice, did the Emperor actually have two apprentices at the same time? Did Darth Maul stop being Palapatine's apprentice after his encounter with Obi-Wan?

> "Any master who instructs more than one apprentice in the ways of the dark side is a **fool**. In time the apprentices will unite their strengths and overthrow the master. It is inevitable; Axiomatic. That is why each master must have only one student."
>   ―Darth Revan's holocron

(Emphasis mine)

We know Palpatine isn't a fool, so how can this be?

Comment: I'm thinking it was so much that he didn't know, but that he didn't *care*. He was of no use to him at this point, so why bother. The charge is to not have two apprentices ... so just kick one to the curb and on to the next. As a side note, didn't Palpatine take Darth Sidious as his apprentice between Maul and Vader?

Comment: @Paulster2: I think you're referring to Count Dooku, aka: Darth Tyranus. Darth Sidious is Palpatine himself. Having said that, isn't Darth Maul surviving now relegated to Legends canon? If so, "canonical sources" might be a bit too strong of a phrase in this context.

Comment: @Ellesedil ... DOH@! actually you are correct ... my Star-Wars-Fu is off today ... but yes, I meant Count Dooku/Darth Tyranus. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Hmm, looks like Maul was in the Clone Wars TV show. I never watched any of it. So yeah, I guess he's alive in Disney canon.

Comment: Palpatine knew that Maul survived but, even though it is canon, me and my friend Leo never believe that Maul actually survived. It is not a bad Idea, considering Maul only had a few scenes, but it is also very unrealistic. What I don't really understand is how Maul got out of that pit. Not only that he was found in another place, he was also found on a completely different planet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Palpatine *did* discover Darth Maul had survived before taking Anakin as his new apprentice.

In Star Wars the Clone Wars, Darth Maul was discovered by Count Dooku/Darth Tyranus's ex aprentice [Savage Opress](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Savage_Opress), who happened to be from the same clan as Darth Maul. After recuperating Darth Maul with the assistance of [Mother Talzin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Talzin), Darth Maul takes Opress as his apprentice and they begin their own plot to rival the emperor.

To make a long story short, Maul and Opress, with the help of [Death Watch](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Watch) take control of Mandalore. **This is when Palpatine discovers that his old apprentice is still alive**, and makes a candid visit to Mandalore where he engages the two Dathomirian Zabrak sith brothers and kills Opress in the episode "The Lawless" in season five of the Clone Wars. The episode ends with Opress's death, and Maul's defeat, but with an indication from Palpatine that though he has replaced Darth Maul, he does have *other* uses for him.

[Quoting Darth Sidious from the clip below (3:36):](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7hBZNsPnyg&feature=youtu.be&t=3m36s)

> "Remember, the one and only reality of the Sith – there can *only* be
>   two. And you are no longer my apprentice; you have been *replaced!*"

[image]

### [Darth Maul & Savage Opress VS Darth Sidious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7hBZNsPnyg)

Comment: I think providing Sidious' quote after he killed Savage would help this answer since the quote directly answers the OP's question. The quote was something along the lines of: *"Remember, the one and only reality of the Sith -- there can only be two. And you are no long my apprentice; you have been replaced!"* This essentially shows that Sidious still values the Rule of Two and does not consider Maul to be his apprentice anymore.

Comment: @jliv902 is this quote in the new Disney canon, or is it part of legends?

Comment: @JasonHutchinson It's from the episode in the answer. The cartoon is considered Disney Canon.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson - I've added the quote, and I've linked to the [exact moment in the video when he says it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7hBZNsPnyg&feature=youtu.be&t=3m36s).

Comment: Darth Sidious will be in so much trouble for violating the Rule of Two.

Comment: Actually, earlier in that season, Obi Wan, Mace Windu, Yoda, and Anikan have a meeting with Palpatine to discuss Darth Maul, so at that point Palpatine/Sidious knew Maul had survived.  Sidious probably chose to ignore it because of a combination of the risk of exposure, and maybe curiosity.  Maybe he wanted to see what Maul would do.  Maybe he'd prove useful.  The incident on Mandalore made it clear that Maul was a threat and that I guess is what made it worth the risk to go out and fight him.